# How to open popup and reload another page?

Tags: php, javascript, refresh

How can I open a popup with some code and it close by itslef when finish it job? And also reload the page that opened the popup. Confused? So am I . Sorry lol

eg:

Page_1 has a button that open a new window (Page_2) with a form. When I submit that Page_2 form, Page_2 should close and Page_1 refresh by it self too.

Is it possible? Can you link a guide or help me somehow?

Im using, PHP, Javascript.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than using a popup which a lot of browsers question and frown upon, have you considered using a floating DIV with some javascript database connectivity perhaps?

Comment: Hm, I dont think I got time and knowledge to do that at this moment :s And if I use _blank window it get better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the parent page you will need a function to load your child page and a function that will reload itself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadPopup(){
    window.open("yourpopup.html");
}

function reloadPage(){
    window.location.reload()
}    
</script>
```

Now on the popup page you can call the parent function with "opener" like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function somethingWasClicked(){
    window.opener.reloadPage();
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You  could use something like this:

```
function refreshParent() {
  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow)

 {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
  window.close();
}
```